# Adding a new array to a multidimensional array item

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to add some details to an array without overwriting the old data.

At the moment I have something like this if I print_r($data)

```
 Array
 (
   [one] => Hello
   [two] => Hello World
 )
```

I then have a function that adds some data to the array

```
 foreach ($rubric as $rs){
      if($rs['position']==1){$data['one']=$rs;}
  if($rs['position']==2){$data['two']=$rs;}
 }
```

This gives me the following if I print_r($data)

```
Array
(
   [one] => Array
      (
         [id] => 1
      )
   [two] => Array
      (
         [id] => 2
      )
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas

What I would like to do is....

```
 foreach ($rubric as $rs){
      if($rs['position']==1){$data['one']['details']=$rs;}
  if($rs['position']==2){$data['two']['details']=$rs;}
 }
```

With the aim of adding a new subarray called "details" within each array item...

Does that make sense? If I try to run that code however I get the following error

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion**

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what would be the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,  [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) [array_unshift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

Array push puts an element at the end. Array unshift adds a number to the beginning of the array.

You can also use the structure

```
$myArray['nameOfNewElement']=$newElement;
```

This adds $newElement to the array $myArray;

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do... that would be prefect but when I try to do that I get "A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion"

Any ideas?

Comment: The previous syntax I put in was a little more advanced, so I changed it. What's in there now should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

According to your question, here is the solution :

```
// sample array
$rubric = array(0=> array("position"=>1),1 => array("position"=>2));
$data = array("one" => "Hello","two" => "hello world");
foreach ($rubric as $rs){
      if($rs['position']==1){
           $d= array_merge($data,$rs);
      }
      if($rs['position']==2){
          $d= array_merge($data,$rs);
      }
 }
print_r($d);
```

Here is the working DEMO : http://codepad.org/rgKiv542

Hope, it'll help  you.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$data['one'] = $rs;`, you are assigning $rs to overwrite the value `"Hello"`.

Perhaps what you were trying to do is

```
$data['three'] = $rs['id'];
```